# Custom API get response only when paramenter changes (jQuery GET)

Tags: jquery, api, xmlhttprequest, response

I am facing a strange problem:

There is an API that belongs to a surf company. Basically, it returns the station location, the wind strength, and so on...

I'm making a call to their API with jQuery. The first time I get the correct response; I can see in Firebug->Net->XHR->Response and I can see a proper JSON object.

When I reload the page, I can't get any response (no response). I can get a response only if I change some parameters in the url.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.get('http://[api_site_url]/[api_key]/?lat=53.904338&lon=-2.028809&distance=200',
           function(data) {
                var jsonp = data;
                alert(jsonp);
           });
});
```

Obviously, `[api_site_url]` and `[api_key]` are replaced with the real URL and API key.

Answer (score 0):

Query "get()" operations are cached in IE unless you pass in a unique URL. The example solution is here: http://www.miuaiga.com/index.cfm/2010/5/30/jQuery-AJAX-get-function-cached-in-IE

Comment: I tried everything: a new parameter with a random number, a $.ajax function with cache: false, $.ajaxSetup with cache:false but nothing. I usually use Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: One more question: what happened if you add your custom parameter to request. Let's call it "_" and add it value with Date.now(). It should make your request unique and ignored by server.

Comment: that was I was trying to do, but it didn't work. I added a &rndm= with a random number, but it didn't work. However, I found a solution: instead of sending, for example: &lat=54.1&lon=1.5 if I fill the value with generated random numbers, it works (lat=54.1123456&lon=1.5123456).